# Hosting my own domain using Google Apps - Mapping not working / Instructions Obsolete

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, hosting, google-apps

I am trying to MAP 'www.mydomain.com' to 'xyzwebsite.appspot.com':

- Created an application in Google Apps using my gmail id and hosted a website successfully. i.e. xyz.appspot.com works fine.
- Registered my domain name mydomain.com with Godaddy and changed the CNAME record for the subdomain 'www' which now points to 'ghs.googlehosted.com'
- Verified mydomain.com for Google Apps successfully
- Tried to go through the instructions from the google link below for MAPPING 'mydomain.com' to 'xyz.appsot.com'

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#serving_your_app_on_a_custom_domain

Everything works fine until I reach Step 6. I couldn't do 'Click Service Settings and choose Sites.' as described in that step. But, from Admin console, I could reach 'Web Address Mapping' via Google Apps > Settings for Sites > Advanced Settings.

All I could see there was 'Add a web new address' blue button, which enables mapping www.mydomain.com' to 'http://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/'. I couldn't find/reach Step 7, 8 and 9  (as in the link above) and configure as suggested. i.e. I couldn't delete any 'www' mapping to sites.google.com, I couldn't find 'Service Settings and choose your app' as in Step 8. I couldn't enable/add/map 'xyz.appspot.com' to 'www.mydomain.com' anywhere.

After many tries, mydomain.com simply points to a blank google sites page now. My xyz website (its google app engine) actually runs in my 'gmail' account but mydomain.com leads to creation of its own google apps business account. It seems that the instructions are outdated. Can someone please point me to the up-to-date instructions? Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve your google apps from www.yourdomaian.com, simply put **www** at the subdoamin column at step 5. It will redirect your request to google app regardless your google site page was set up or not.